# Searching for minute binned OHLCV Cryptocurrency data from 5 January 2018 to 7 September 2018

Tags: programming, historical-data, cryptocurrency

As the title states, searching for OHLCV data (USD) from the dates listed for these coins:

[ADA, BCH, CVC, DASH, EOS, ETC, ETH, LTC, MANA, OMG, BCN, BTC, CND, DATA, ETP, GNT, NEO, NXT, QASH]

I'm a university student who is taking on a personal project of replicating the results of "Statistical Arbitrage in Cryptocurrency Markets" (Fischer et al., 2019). Here is a list of everything I've tried so far:

- Tried using many different API keys, each one has their own respective restrictions
- Downloading data directly from Binance given each Crypto's respective URL using a python script (was going great at first, however much of the currencies I require do not have data as far back as January 2018)
- Scoured various Kaggle crypto datasets, same issues happened above as much of the data is aggregated from Bitfenix/Binance and is the exact same

Any ideas? I'm a broke college student who does not have the financial freedom to spend hundreds of dollars on premium API services. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Someone kind who is familiar with crypto markets might answer, but normally these type of "data request" questions are not suitable for the Quant Finance SE website: the community here is more about quant finance theory, rather than sourcing specific data (and more so data for crypto, which falls outside of the scope of this website all together, unless it's a derivative pricing question or other - theoretical finance - type of question).